# send a floating point number in the register

Tags: c, sdk, xilinx, vivado, zynq

I am writing a software in c code in sdk vivado, 
i have this function for writing to the register

```
MYIP_CELL_TOP_mWriteReg(BaseAddress, RegOffset, Data) \
Xil_Out32((BaseAddress) + (RegOffset), (u32)(Data))
```

as you see one of the parameters of this function is **Data** which is **U32** and U32  means :

```
unsigned long   U32
```

i want to send a floating point number in the register.

like this number  **0.0807836f** , what i did,  i separate the decimal and fractional part and send them to different registers.( then i want to use other function to read from registers and i can concatenate them )

my problem is when i send them to the registers , the fractional part is **807836**  , which is would like to have **0807836** .

i wrote this code :

```
Xfloat32 a = 0.0807836f
        int whole, thousandths ;
        whole = a;
        thousandths = (a - whole) * 100000;

        MYIP_CELL_TOP_mWriteReg(XPAR_MYIP_CELL_TOP_V1_0_0_0_S00_AXI_LITE_BASEADDR ,ADDR_CLUSTER_INIT_DATA_DATA_0_OFFSET, whole);
        MYIP_CELL_TOP_mWriteReg(XPAR_MYIP_CELL_TOP_V1_0_0_0_S00_AXI_LITE_BASEADDR ,ADDR_CLUSTER_INIT_DATA_DATA_1_OFFSET, thousandths );
```

Please help me how i can send fractional part like this 0807836.

thank you in advance

Comment: Not clear for me. What is the problem? An integer `0807836` or `807836` is the same thing. What you have to know is that that number must be divided for your factor, i.e. `100000`

Comment: Note: don't use homebrew fixed-width types. Use the standard-provided types from `stdint.h`. If that is from the SDK, I'd be suspicious about its quality. Said that, what is your question

Comment: I am not sure this way is a good way, if you have a suggestion about how i can write and read  floating point number in the register, please help me .

Comment: What is the representation your hardware is using for the floating point number?